# How to keep triangles from connecting across voxel mesh

Tags: 3d, javascript, webgl

I am working on a voxel engine and have just started learning webgl. I have generated a list of Vertices and Indices by using Array.concat() on a template array and adding a value based on my position in loop.

```
var verticesTemplate = [
    // Front face
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,

    // Top face
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,

    // Right face
    0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
    0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
    0.5, -0.5,  0.5,

    // Bottom face
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,

    // Left face
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,

    // Back face
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
];
var indicesTemplate = [
    0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
    4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
    8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
    12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
    16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
    20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
];
var WorldVertices = [];
var WorldIndices = [];
var IndexLoopIndex = 0;

function generateMeshData() {
    for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        var blockVertices = [].concat(verticesTemplate);
        addToX(verticesTemplate, blockVertices, x);
        for(var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            addToY(verticesTemplate, blockVertices, y);
            for(var z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
                var block = blocks[x][y][z];
                if(block.isActive === true) {
                    // adds a value of 1(The blockSize) to all z coordinates in verticesTemplate and adds to end of WorldVertices
                    addToZ(verticesTemplate, blockVertices, z);
                    WorldVertices = WorldVertices.concat(blockVertices);

                    var indices = [].concat(indicesTemplate);
                    addToXYZ(indicesTemplate, indices, 24*IndexLoopIndex);
                    WorldIndices = WorldIndices.concat(indices);
                    IndexLoopIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

The problem is that the triangles are skewed after the mesh is rendered using gl.drawElements. And I can't figure out why. So how can I keep triangles from being drawn that connect cubes?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In the end I just wrote 3 functions: CreateCube, addVertex and addTriangle. Here they are.

```
function addVertex(vertexArray) {
    WorldVertices = WorldVertices.concat(vertexArray);

    // returns a vertexId that is used to map triangles to vertices array
    return (WorldVertices.length/3)-1;
}

function addTriangle(vertexIdArray) {
    WorldIndices = WorldIndices.concat(vertexIdArray);
}

function CreateCube(x, y, z, block) {
    // 8 points on a cube are extracted using coordinates from for-loop
    var p0 = vec3.fromValues(x-1, y-1, z+1);
    var p1 = vec3.fromValues(x+1, y-1, z+1);
    var p2 = vec3.fromValues(x+1, y+1, z+1);
    var p3 = vec3.fromValues(x-1, y+1, z+1);
    var p4 = vec3.fromValues(x+1, y-1, z-1);
    var p5 = vec3.fromValues(x-1, y-1, z-1);
    var p6 = vec3.fromValues(x-1, y+1, z-1);
    var p7 = vec3.fromValues(x+1, y+1, z-1);

    // vertexIds
    var v0, v1, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7;

    v0 = addVertex(Array.from(p0));
    v1 = addVertex(Array.from(p1));
    v2 = addVertex(Array.from(p2));
    v3 = addVertex(Array.from(p3));

    addTriangle([v0, v1, v2]);
    addTriangle([v0, v2, v3]);

    v4 = addVertex(Array.from(p4));
    v5 = addVertex(Array.from(p5));
    v6 = addVertex(Array.from(p6));
    v7 = addVertex(Array.from(p7));

    addTriangle([ v4, v5, v6]);
    addTriangle([ v4, v6, v7]);

    // Right

    v1 = addVertex(Array.from(p1));
    v4 = addVertex(Array.from(p4));
    v7 = addVertex(Array.from(p7));
    v2 = addVertex(Array.from(p2));

    addTriangle([ v1, v4, v7]);
    addTriangle([ v1, v7, v2]);

    // left

    v5 = addVertex(Array.from(p5));
    v0 = addVertex(Array.from(p0));
    v3 = addVertex(Array.from(p3));
    v6 = addVertex(Array.from(p6));

    addTriangle([ v5, v0, v3]);
    addTriangle([ v5, v3, v6]);

    // Top

    v3 = addVertex(Array.from(p3));
    v2 = addVertex(Array.from(p2));
    v7 = addVertex(Array.from(p7));
    v6 = addVertex(Array.from(p6));

    addTriangle([ v3, v2, v7]);
    addTriangle([ v3, v7, v6]);

    // Bottom

    v5 = addVertex(Array.from(p5));
    v4 = addVertex(Array.from(p4));
    v1 = addVertex(Array.from(p1));
    v0 = addVertex(Array.from(p0));

    addTriangle([v5, v4, v1]);
    addTriangle([v5, v1, v0]);
}

for(var x = -8; x < 4; x++) {
    for(var y = -8; y < 4; y++) {
        for(var z = -8; z < 4; z++) {
            var block = blocks[x][y][z];
            if(block.isActive === false)
                continue;

            // 2 is the blockSize  
            CreateCube(x*2, y*2, z*2, block);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]